# Can my training and testing data be of different timesteps length?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to use a deep neural network for a regression problem. I have 50 samples of 600 timesteps each. I am planning to use 40 for training and 10 for validation. 
If it matters, I have used a neural network with input layer, lstm, dense, dense(output).
After my network gets trained, can I use it to predict for a timeseries of a smaller length (200 timesteps)?

The input and output dimensions (i.e. features) will remain same, just the length (i.e. number of timesteps) is smaller